# Angular.js changes doesnt applying to rails api

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Im dealing with some problems when changing data at the angular.js controller, **the data changed in angular, doesnt apply to the rails api**. The data seems changed but when refreshing the page, the "old" data from rails come again, im sending data from angular by a PUT request.

**No errors at javascript console.**

I let some code here:

**ReservaController.js.coffee**

```
App.controller 'ReservaController', ['$scope','Reserva', ($scope, Reserva) ->
  $scope.reservas = Reserva.query()

  $scope.update1 = (reserva) ->
   console.log reserva
   console.log reserva.id
   reserva.confirmada = true
   reserva.$update(id: reserva.id)
]
```

**reservas.js.coffee**

```
App.factory "Reserva", ["$resource", ($resource) ->
    return $resource("/reservas_display/:id", id: "@id",
      update:
        method: "PUT"
    )
]
```

**/reservas/index.html.erb**

```
<span ng-if="!reserva.confirmada">
   <a class="btn btn-mini btn-success" ng-click="update1(reserva)">Confirmar</a>
</span>
```

**reservas_controller.rb**

```
# PATCH/PUT /reservas/1
# PATCH/PUT /reservas/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @reserva.update(reserva_params)
        format.html { redirect_to reservas_url, notice: 'Reserva was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @reserva.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

any idea whats going on?

Comment: Try `reserva.$update({id: reserva.id})`

Comment: @zishe already tried, still failing...

Comment: This is coffeescript. Where curly braces are banned.